# How to import Google's Speech-to-text on React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I'm trying to import [Google's speech-to-text](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-usage-nodejs) npm package into my React Native project but I'm not able to do it. There's an example documentation to import (require) on node.js but I can't make it work on React Native, this is the example on Google page:

```
  // Imports the Google Cloud client library
  const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');

  // Creates a client
  const client = new speech.SpeechClient();
```

I have installed it via npm but can't call it using require like the one above and neither with import:

```
import Speech from '@google-cloud/speech'
```

It just print that they're undefined, How should I import it?

Comment: that's about node js (server code), and irrelevant to react native